# Declaring multiple parameterised class object in java

Tags: java, generics

we can declare a method in Java as

```
public static <T extends ClassTakesA<A>, A extends ClassTakesBC<B, C>, B extends ClassB, C extends ClassC> T MyFunc(Class<T> clazz) {
    T obj = null;
    try {
        obj = clazz.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

So that at compile time or in IDE we already know the parameter to MyFunc() must be bounded by T. This works great because

```
MyFunc(Object.class) // good, gives compile time error as expected
MyFunc(ClassTakesA.class) // good, although need @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

Now if I need to declare the parameter to MyFunc() first, how should I declare it so that I can get compile time (or in IDE) error if the parameter is not bounded by T? e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class myClass = Object.class;
    MyFunc(myClass);  // no error at compile time, but failed in runtime
}
```

Tried this but its wrong syntax

```
    Class<T extends ClassTakesA<A>, A extends ClassTakesBC<B, C>, B extends ClassB, C extends ClassC> myClass;
```

And by the way, how do you get rid of the @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")?

---

A suggestion was to use

```
Class<ClassTakesA> myClass = ClassTakesA.class;
```

But I do not allow passing

```
ClassTakesA<ClassZ> classTakesANot = new ClassTakesA<ClassZ>();
Class<ClassTakesA> myClass = classTakesANot.getClass();
MyFunc(myClass);
```

as `ClassZ` does not extend `ClassTakesBC<B, C>`

Comment: Just for the record: method names start lowercase in java. Always.

Comment: A sidenote: prefer `return class.newInstance();` in `try`-blocks, and `return null` (if it's really worthy) or `throw new RuntimeException(ex)` in the `catch`-block. For good.

Comment: @GhostCat it's a naming convention not a hard rule.

Comment: If you change `Class myClass` to `Class<?> myClass` you will get the error

Comment: `Class<Object> myClass = Object.class; MyFunc(myClass);` will give you a compile-time error.

Comment: @Spotted [really](http://ideone.com/38G8Uk)?

Comment: @Spotted I understand what you are trying to do. But the purpose is not to get compile time error so that the program won't run at all. I need the correct way to declare myClass so that wrong assignment can be captured at compile time.

Comment: See: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) for explanation of why `Class myClass = Object.class;` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

As for method invocation you should declare it as

```
    Class<ClassTakesA> myClass = ClassTakesA.class;
    MyFunc(myClass);
```

This way you provides compiler some information about myClass so it can check during compilation.

As for warning you cannot rid of them because generics are not exist in runtime, where class objects live.

-- Add guava TypeToken --

Also you can try to use Guava's TypeToken to get rid of warning, but it will introduce another warning in `obj = (T)...`

```
public static <T extends ClassTakesA<A>, A extends ClassTakesBC<B, C>, B extends ClassB, C extends ClassC> T foo(TypeToken<T> clazz) {
    T obj = null;
    try {
        obj = (T) clazz.getRawType().newInstance();
        System.out.println("1 " + obj);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}

private <T extends ClassTakesA<A>, A extends ClassTakesBC<B, C>, B extends ClassB, C extends ClassC> void test() {
    TypeToken<T> typeToken = new TypeToken<T>(ClassTakesA.class) { };
    foo(typeToken);
}
```

Comment: Hummm, this loses all the boundaries checking where myClass must be ClassTakesA<A> or its subclass where A must be ClassTakesBC<B, C> or its subclass and so on.

Comment: Yes it's, unfortunately.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html all generics are erased during compilation, so classes in runtime are 'clean'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use T, A, B , C you will need to add them to the class declaration, not only the method declaration:

```
  public class MyClass <T extends ClassTakesA<A>, A extends ClassTakesBC<B, C>, B extends ClassB, C extends ClassC>  {

public T MyFunc(Class<T> clazz) {
  T obj = null;
  try {
    obj = clazz.newInstance();
  } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return obj;
}
```

}

And then you can create a class which extends ClassTakesA, i.e:

```
public class ExtendsClassTakesA<A> extends ClassTakesA<A>{}
```

And call your function with:

```
Class<ExtendsClassTakesA> myClass = ExtendsClassTakesA.class;
MyFunc(myClass);
```

Comment: Interesting idea. May be yours is neater in some cases. But I am after a simpler solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working. It turns out to be a simple replacement of the `T, A, B, C` to `?` e.g.

`Class<? extends ClassTakesA<? extends ClassTakesBC<? extends ClassB, ? extends ClassC>>> myClass;`